# Call a second animation once the first one is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am having trouble figuring out how to call an animation once a div has finished loading. What I mean is I have a menu system once pressed will slide out and display my website links. What I am trying to do is have the menu panel slide out and then call my menu link animation.

**Code used to fade in menu links**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-item').hide();                    
    (function animatenext(elem){
        elem.eq(0).fadeIn("slow", function(){
        (elem=elem.slice(1)).length && animatenext(elem);
    });
    })($('.menu-item'))
 });
```

**Code used to slide menu**

```
 $("body").not(".gn-icon-menu").click(function() {
 $(".gn-icon-menu").removeClass("on");
   });

 $(".gn-icon-menu").click(function(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 $(this).toggleClass("on");

 });    

 $(function () {
  window.status = 0;
  $('#menu').click(function () {
    if ($('header').is('.open')) {
        var open = $('header').is('.open');
        $('#slideWrapper')['slide' + (open ? 'Up' : 'Down')](400);
        $('header').animate({
            bottom: (open ? '-' : '+') + '=200'
        }, 400, function () {
            $('header').removeClass('open');
        });

        if ($('.navFooter button').hasClass('activetoggle')) {
            $('.navFooter button').removeClass('activetoggle');
            $('.navFooter button').addClass('slidingPanel');
            $('.navFooter button').text('Footer');
        } 
        if ($('.gn-icon-menu').hasClass('activetoggle')) {
            $('.gn-icon-menu').removeClass('activetoggle');
            $('.gn-icon-menu').addClass('gn-icon-menu');

        } 
    }
    if (window.status == 0) {
        $('#slidingMenu').stop().animate({
            left: '0px'
        }, 500);
        window.status = 1;
        $('#slidingMenu').addClass('open');
    } else {
        $('#slidingMenu').stop().animate({
            left: '-100%'
        }, 500);
        window.status = 0;
        $('#slidingMenu').removeClass('open');
    }
    $('#slidingMenu').click(function () {
        if ($('#slidingMenu').is('.open')) {
    $('#slidingMenu').stop().animate({
        left: '-100%'
    }, 500);
    window.status = 0;
    $('#slidingMenu').removeClass('open');
}
    });
 });
 })
```

How can I call my menu links ".menu-item" to animate every time when my menu system has finished sliding out `#slidingMenu`?

Full code http://jsfiddle.net/xhnsnbrz/6/

Comment: You can use add class on load ALONG WITH scrollreveal.js

Comment: how can that be done with the code I am using? @HarshalGajjar

Comment: I've not coded for web since a long time, however, I can still provide you the method: https://github.com/julianlloyd/scrollReveal.js Scroll reveal allows us to animations for div when the div comes into view, therefore, if you initialize a class with this option and then add it (using onload along with some delay) to a division (or span in this case), you'll get your desired result. :)

Comment: that does not seem to work within my code @HarshalGajjar

Comment: no need to be sorry thank you for trying @HarshalGajjar

Comment: But if you make the time interval of loading of the menu fixed then won't delaying the visibility toggle help?

Comment: it should but for some reason I am unable to get it to work. Also this just seems to heavy in code by using scrollReveal @HarshalGajjar

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call an event once the first event has finished](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999911/call-an-event-once-the-first-event-has-finished)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger a function when the animation is done:

```
$("#slidingMenu").stop().animate(
    {
       left: '0px'
    }, 500, animateItemMenu);

function animateItemMenu(){
    // ... write your code here
}
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I have tried doing that but it forces the #slidingMenu to display instead of hidden until clicked. @WissamEl-Kik