# Call an event once the first event has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having problem with calling an event once one event has finished animating.

I have 2 events running. What I am trying to achieve is when the first event is completely finished (it is controlled by a click function) then I want to run the second event which will fade in my links.I tried applying a .done function for when #slidingMenu has animated in but the links do not fade in once the animation is completed, they just stay static.

**Menu (on click)**

```
 $(function () {
   window.status = 0;
   $('#menu').click(function () {
  if ($('header').is('.open')) {
    var open = $('header').is('.open');
    $('#slideWrapper')['slide' + (open ? 'Up' : 'Down')](400);
    $('header').animate({
        bottom: (open ? '-' : '+') + '=200'
    }, 400, function () {
        $('header').removeClass('open');
    });

    if ($('.navFooter button').hasClass('activetoggle')) {
        $('.navFooter button').removeClass('activetoggle');
        $('.navFooter button').addClass('slidingPanel');
        $('.navFooter button').text('Footer');
    } 
    if ($('.gn-icon-menu').hasClass('activetoggle')) {
        $('.gn-icon-menu').removeClass('activetoggle');
        $('.gn-icon-menu').addClass('gn-icon-menu');

    } 
}
if (window.status == 0) {
    $('#slidingMenu').stop().animate({
        left: '0px'
    }, 500);
    window.status = 1;
    $('#slidingMenu').addClass('open');
} else {
    $('#slidingMenu').stop().animate({
        left: '-100%'
    }, 500);
    window.status = 0;
    $('#slidingMenu').removeClass('open');
}
$('#slidingMenu').click(function () {
    if ($('#slidingMenu').is('.open')) {
$('#slidingMenu').stop().animate({
    left: '-100%'
}, 500);
window.status = 0;
$('#slidingMenu').removeClass('open');
 }
});
 });
 })
```

**Menu links fade in**

```
  $.when.apply(this, '#slidingMenu').done(function() {
        $('.menu-item').each(function(i) {
  $(this).fadeOut(0).delay(1000*i).fadeIn(1850);
      });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xhnsnbrz/7/

Comment: so sorry I forgot to insert it. I made the edit to my comment and placed a fiddle link @Eirenaios

Comment: You have to use callbacks, a callback is a function that is call after the current function finishe, example: fadeIn(1850, function (){console.log('I have finished :)');});

Comment: where would I add that callback to? @sudo.ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a callback function to the `animate` function, which runs when the animation is finished:

```
$(element).animate(options, timeout, callbackFunction);
```

So in your case, you could put your fadeOut inside a function there:

```
$('#slidingMenu').stop().animate({
    left: '0px'
}, 500, function(){
    $('.menu-item').each(function(i) {
      $(this).fadeOut(0).delay(1000*i).fadeIn(1850);
    });
});
```

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhnsnbrz/9/)

As you see, the menu items are briefly visible because they only are hidden once your animation has finished. A better way would be to do the hiding before you even start the animation, and only do the `fadeIn` in the callback:

```
$('.menu-item').fadeOut(0); // no need for an each here

$('#slidingMenu').stop().animate({
    left: '0px'
}, 500, function(){
    $('.menu-item').each(function(i) {
      $(this).delay(1000*i).fadeIn(1850);
    });
});
```

Also with a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhnsnbrz/10/)

Comment: it works but there is one issue. You will notice on your Fiddle that the links are displayed first then disappear and then fade back in. How can I can fix this from happening @Stephan Muller

Comment: I already foresaw that problem and updated the answer a few minutes ago :)

Comment: is there away to fade the links out once you close the menu @Stephan Muller

Comment: Sure, on the close function you could add a similar callback function.

Answer (score -2):

what i would do is have a variable that is only set to True at the end of the first event. e.g.

check = False

Your_event_1
check = True

if(check == True):
    Your_event_2

Comment: how would I implement that into my code and how would that even work? @AGMC

Comment: just after #slidingMenu has animated, add the 'check = true' line. just before the link fade add the if statement. and before any executable code add the definition of what 'check' is.